# "Controlling" for population/sample sizes when looking at rates?

Tags: ratio, percentage, controlling-for-a-variable

I have a pretty basic understanding of statistics, so please bear with me:

- I'm making an index (ranking) of sector performance
- I am including indicators such as "Percent of profitable firms in sector", etc.
- I am noticing that the number of firms in each industry (or I guess the sample/population size) greatly influences the ranking of sectors within indicators such as the one mentioned above
- Generally, sectors with a smaller number of firms are often at an extreme highs or lows: if two of out two firms are profitable, then the sector ranks at the top and if two out of two firms are not profitable, then the sector ranks at the bottom, etc.

I understand the phenomena above is mathematically consistent with how I have formulated my indicators, but I would like for my index/ranking to somehow control for sector size such that I mitigate these extremes. I.E. I want a sector with 1000 firms profitable out of 1002 firms to be at least equal to, if not better than an industry with 2 firms out of 2 firms profitable.

Any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: I can't really tell from your description, but it's possible that you just expect more variability with smaller sample sizes because there isn't as much data to stabilize metrics. See *The Most Dangerous Equation* ([pdf](http://faculty.cord.edu/andersod/MostDangerousEquation.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you for the response! that was very helpful in understanding the issue, and a fun read.

Any ideas how people have overcome the problem, i.e. adjusted rankings so that they are not over/under ranking units that have a smaller sample size and thus a larger variance? 

It has been suggested to me to just manually exclude extreme cases where there is only one firm in a sector (by this I mean one registered company within a specific industry, for example oil exploitation only has one major state producer in Serbia), but I was wondering if a clever solution that is more systematic exists?

Comment: Perhaps there is some way I can adjust measures such as "Share of Profitable Firms Within Sector" such that the measures are less susceptible to the "overall numbers of firms within the sector"?

Comment: I don't know enough about your situation to provide any concrete advice, but a Bayesian approach might be an option. The idea would be that all firms are given the same prior / baseline, & the magnitude of the difference & the amount of data to support that difference is allowed to shift each firm away from the prior.

Comment: that's a great idea, I will explore, thank you! If you happen to know any existing explanations of similar models that would be greatly appreciated as well!